# How to create a DBA user in oracle 10g Express Edition Using Visual Basic 6?

Tags: oracle, vb6

Coming straight to my question, I want to create a user in Oracle 10g Express edition from inside visual basic 6. I know how to do it using oracle directly but it will be of great help if someone tells me how to do it using visual basic 6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in this procedure. Then all this procedure from .VBS.

The .sql script to be executed from sqlplus can look like

```
create user &1 identified by &2;
grant connect to &1;
```

execute is using

```
sqlplus user/pass@db @script.sql UserA PassA
```

but I really think this is not good solution.

Comment: Sorry to say but I am a novice regarding visual basic and oracle. So, i am not able to implement your suggestion.
I want to ask that can't I solve my problem by running a sql script using a batch file with shell command

Comment: then you have to execute `sqlplus` somehow.

Comment: yah, i know how to execute sqlplus
i write the following in a batch file
sqlplus slm/bhaskar @d:\slm\sql-scripts\delete.sql

and then run this batch file to execute delete.sql

but I want to know what should I write in the sql script which on running will create a new DBA user in oracle.

Thanks for a quick response

Comment: PS:- I googled a lot for it but everywhere I got the method of creating users through GUI of Oracle not through sql command line

Comment: Thanks for your quick response once again. I will try it for sure and I will try to read more about what you suggested first.or sure :)